# Using prepositions after '' regret , '' bemoan ''

Tags: prepositions

I give some sentences I saw below ;

> 1) you'll *regret* it.
>   2) they *bemoan* lack of fund.

My question is that if i use a preposition like "about" after these above given synonyms whether it be wrong or not, and when I write sentences using them, could I use "for" or "about" after them?

Comment: How are you proposing you would use *for* or *about* in those sentences? I can't think of any way of inserting either word that would be grammatical. (For instance, *you'll regret* ***[for / about]*** *it* is not at all grammatical.)

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 should use "lack of funds" or "lack of funding" not "lack of fund". And "**the** lack of funds" would be better yet.

I don't see a plausible and valid way to use 'about" in variants of the example sentences. A use of "for" here also seems dubious at best. Perhaps if you were to provide your best attempts, a better answer could be given.

Comment: I could not understand. Can you or anyone explain it clearly?